# How long is never?

Tags: discussion

I keep revisiting this question: [Reminder: Unanswered + Time != Too Localised](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6492/reminder-unanswered-time-too-localised) in which @Oli states

"The idea of removing older questions is okay but only under certain conditions:

- The asker has been asked a follow-up question and never replied (or never edited their post to add requested information) and it doesn't have a viable +1 answer"

etc. See original question if you want the full list. My question is: In the context above, "How long is never?"

Comment: The goal of [*that* post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6492/reminder-unanswered-time-too-localised) was to stop a wave of closure-attempts on questions *just* because they were old or not made perfect the same day. Just use some common sense for what's reasonable. Certainly no less than a few days.

Comment: @Oli Thank you. This makes perfect sense.  I always attempt to get further information (if necessary) and try to reasonable at all times. I don't believe I've ever flagged a question that was as recent as a few days unless it was abundantly clear to the casual observer that is was outside of scope or otherwise not salvageable. I would assume the same overall goals exist today as existed then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use common sense here.

1. Read the question
2. Has it been improved, or touched recently?
3. Is there anything you can do to salvage it? Maybe an edit, or a share, or a bounty?

If it's just sitting there for months and there's no activity then it's probably abandoned. There should at least be *some* kind of activity somewhere.

Comment: I will continue to do so. Thank you for treating a relative newb to this site with respect.

Comment: Follow up question: how much is "recently"? How about the questions that has high activity (lots of comments) yet remain unanswered?

Comment: It's also a good idea to check if the OP has been seen recently at all. If he hasn't been seen since very recently after he asked the question or in the last year then it is almost definitely abandoned. (cc: @ElderGeek)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Briam based on the answer above "recently" < "months"

Comment: @ElderGeek no,nonono, waiting or "holding hands" is definitivelly not the way to go... Stack Exchange and everyone on mSE will tell you *do not wait*. Let me put it this way, would you wait to vote up or answer a question? BTW, my name is written B-R-A-I-**A**-M, at least try to write it correctly

Comment: @ElderGeek more reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/213575

Comment: @Braiam My apologies for misspelling your name. I certainly didn't intend any disrespect. There's no need to emphasize your spelling skills, I'm not a 3 year old. The above is a perfect example of your typical tone. Please try to understand that we are all here attempting to improve the site. To the best of my knowledge this is not a dictatorship. I think your posts sound demanding at best and condescending at worst. I don't believe that this represents best practices for building a consensus.

Comment: @ElderGeek, is not the first time that you misspell my name, there's a tool tip that helps you to auto complete the name. Condescending I'm not, I don't even know what "condescending" means, not it is my interest to dwell is such minute thing. My main interest and worry is the path this community is traveling following this counseling and your actions. [There](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5776/) [have](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6958/) been several discussions about this topic, [one recently](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/10448/), [yet the problem persist](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8374/).

Comment: Dwelling in discussions about "how long should we wait", "how long to take action", etc., is not productive and even counter-productive. Stack Exchange ask you to **act now** if we see something wrong. That's the *only thing* that I ask you to take into account.

Comment: @Braiam thank you for sharing your knowledge. Allow me to share some of mine. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condescending

Comment: @ElderGeek that still doesn't explain how could I been condescending, but whatever, button line here is "how long is never" = 0 seconds.

Comment: @Braiam It appears many would disagree that 0 seconds is long enough to allow a post to develop. I happen to be one of them.

Comment: @ElderGeek plot twist: we have to wait to upvote a good post, which is on topic, relevant or correct. Give it a through. BTW, this has been discussed until satiety, [everyone says you don't have to wait](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112664/213575).

Comment: @Braiam the discussion you linked to applies to **answers** my question was in regard to **questions!** Again, thank you for sharing.

Comment: you are still lost in the wood @ElderGeek, any kind of voting should be done immediately. [I think I already linked this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/213575) which is regarding to close votes (which can only be applied to questions, and the same propaganda is running, **vote immediately**.

Comment: @Braiam I want to thank you for your input and your rapid research into questions and answers that support your views. I feel the the more logical guidance to my question was provided by the comment from Oli and the answer from Jorge. Perhaps we can agree to disagree on this point and move on to the sserious business of improving the site.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, what are you doing reading that +1 year old question? It's no longer relevant today. If you are seeking guidance on that post just drop it.

Secondly, the problem with the general tone of the question is that promote a *passive approach* when engaging users/askers (comment, wait, comment again, wait, VtC, wait, wait a bit more, etc.) which simply **doesn't work**. Such behavior motived Stack Exchange to write the blog post and, at the same time with the title, ask us to [Vote Early, Vote Ofter](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/), which can be colloquially translated to "vote first, ask question later".

The post you link to, was referring to the fact that people where trying to close unanswered questions that kept waiting for answers for a long time (hence the title), but didn't took into account the fact that there are several factors that have to come in play to get a question answered:

- The question can be reasonably answered.
- There are people that can answer it.
- The activity cycle of each question.

The first case should be closed. Done. No waits, no buts, but just plain and pure closure *and* deletion. People will say that such approach is aggressive, but the system already waits **a year** to delete uninteresting questions (no votes), and yet such conservative period of time [is being reviewed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/792066) over other parts of the network.

The second, can be easily solved giving exposure and linking anywhere else, which in fact I've done several times with interesting questions that I've linked in UL chatroom that I've found when cleaning tags.

The third, the system is supposed to take care of it, yet, it depends of us humans to decide what cruft to delete and what to keep, and we seriously suck at optimizing the system job, since we decide to leave open and upvoted several questions that should be closed/downvoted. Is a problem with what the community believes is a "good question", and the long trail of similar asked questions that remains in the system also promotes this believe. BTW, people which questions were automatically deleted [can undelete them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235254/213575), so you have nothing to fear about deleting questions where OP came back alive, again.

So, to actually answer your question "How long is never?" the answer is: 0 seconds. Waiting for some kind of activity is like, while you are in front of the market and know that the milk is almost expiring, you decide go home and wait until it expires so you go out and buy more.

If you can solve the problem **now**, just solve it.

Comment: Your tone leaves a great deal to be desired. If it's not relevant it would/should be downvoted into oblivion. Furthermore, I'm reading a 1+ year old post because I wasn't **here** 1+ years ago. Are you advocating a position of zero research? Do you feel history has no lessons? I'm baffled by what appears to be constant anger and frustration on your part.

Comment: @ElderGeek but if you see **the context** of such question, you will notice that: 1. It was during a [clean up campaign](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2651/169736), which has a set of "rules" to participate 2. the behavior is no longer seen anywhere 3. the close reason itself (too localized) prompted people to abuse it. History is there, but not to repeat them. My post, tries to tell you that you shall not use such post as guidance for your actions, since it's obsolete and in fact obstructive. If you are having doubts in *how to interpret it*, it's because you are attempting to apply it. Is akin

Comment: to try a method to fly a state-of-the-art ship with the manual of some previous century machine manual. Is just not going to work.

Comment: Still baffled by your tone.

Comment: @ElderGeek what "tone" you are talking about? You can't *hear me* to know my "tone", so what's the matter? Did I said something wrong?

Comment: Chalk it up to my failure to _interpret_ your statements properly if you like. Based on the upvotes on my comments I'm not the only one who thinks you come across as just a bit on the rude and condescending side.